# Crashcourse to WordPress development workflow

Tags: php, wordpress, testing, tdd, development-environment

I'm a Java/Scala web-app developper, but I might have to dive head-first into WordPress. I am now preparing in anticipation of that. I am mostly looking for best practices.

The workflow should answer following (broad) questions:

- How to run tests against the whole WordPress platform (to check if I didn't break anything), and how to run tests for the modules/features I am developing (how to do TDD)?
- How should changes be forwarded from Dev to Production environment in a non-destructive manner? Provided Git is used for version control.

I understand that these questions are quite broad, but this tech stack (PHP, WordPress) is quite new to me.

Comment: Unfortunately the "best practice" for WordPress is arguably to avoid it for anything professional.

Comment: @CD001 I am inclined to agree with you. Out of interest, what CMS might be deemed professionally acceptable in the php world?

Comment: Good question and it sort of depends on what you want it to do - I'm not really qualified to answer as I work in house and we have an RYO solution but it might be worth taking a look on : http://www.opensourcecms.com/

Comment: I think you answered the second half of your question yourself: Use Git to move code between development, staging, and production!

Comment: @JimMaguire except that if there's a live DB involved, it will get clobbered.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress core has a set of phpunit tests. You can find documentation on running those tests at http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/automated-testing/ . Not many themes or plugins have test suites available, so you'll either have to write your own (and contribute them back to the community!) or build Selenium tests to verify the end result is ok.

For testing your own code, [WP Mock](https://github.com/10up/wp_mock) might be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some developments since this question was asked! There are now mature BDD / TDD tools for WordPress. [WP-Codeception](http://codeception.com/for/wordpress) is the tool of choice, since it incorporates Behat, PHPunit, WP-CLI and others. Codeception can run Gherkin files, just like Cucumber.

The WordPress modules for Codeception allow you to do WordPress "unit" tests in a variety of ways. You can snapshot the database, you can mock WordPress core functions, and you can do Selenium tests in the browser. You can get started here:

[WordPress-BDD.com](https://wordpress-bdd.com)